# Two String variables of equal value are not comparing to be equal (android)

Tags: string, comparison, string-comparison

I have two variables, one is a String array that is filled from a database, and the other is generated in the program, and I want to execute code if they are equal. I have verified that they have the same value, but the comparison seems to fail.

In this case, the element of the String array is also equal to "2", but the comparison fails.

```
if (r3.isChecked())
     {
          choosenButton = "2";
          if (choosenButton == Global.dbCorrectAnswer[0])
          {
             Toast.makeText(MySchoolOnline.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use equals to compare the variables:

```
choosenButton.equals(Global.dbCorrectAnswer[0])
```